# get folder list of windows computer via bluetooth in java?

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth

I need to build an java program that puts/gets files from a remote windows pc via Bluetooth; the code must also browse the remote filesystem. I've read something about OBEX but have really not found any example for windows. How can it be implemented in a program?

Comment: The same way you would do it on a local machine.  You need a program running on the remote computer that will browse the filesystem for you and send that information over the link.

Comment: Ah, c'mon.  Really?  Word-for-word duplicate of linked question.